# a value of type int cannot be assigned to an entity of type node

Tags: list, structure

I practice structures and I got error like that:

*operand types are incompatible("node*" and "int")*,
where node is name of mu structure. Error is appearing in while(), in (p->next == p->val). How can I check if next object on the list is this one which Im looking for to make it working?

Code has to delete given by me number from list, and It needs to use this structure.

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;
};
void DelGiven(node *H, int x)
{
    node *p = H;
    if (H != NULL)
    {
        while ((p->next != NULL) && (p->next == p->val))
        {
            node *p2;
            p = p->next;
            p2 = p->next;
            p->next = p2->next;
            delete p2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you going to do by this code? you are deleting all nodes after p unless `(p->next == p->val)` , but what this mean `p->next == p->val` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not clearly understand your question, but it seems you want to remove all nodes that their values are equal to x, and if that's your desire this will be your answer:

```
void DelGiven(node *H, int x)
{
    node *p = H;
    node *pre = null;
    if (H != NULL)
    {
        while ((p != NULL))
        {
            if (p->val==x){
                if (pre !=NULL) { pre->next = p->next; }
                delete p;
                p=pre->next;
            }else{
                pre = p;
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and if you want to delete x number of nodes (from top of the list) this will help:

```
void DelGiven(node *H, int x)
{
    node *p = H;
    if (H != NULL)
    {
        int i=0;
        while ((p->next != NULL) && (i<x))
        {
            i++;
            node *p2;
            p = p->next;
            p2 = p->next;
            p->next = p2->next;
            delete p2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

p->next is of type node*, p->val is of type int. So you get a mismatch of data types.
I guess that you need to compare the val field of next node to the val field of the current node.
So create a variable to store p->next, let's say pNext = p->next and later compare the values, pNext->val ==p->val.